# Disable custom dropdown time by datepicker + if day disabled a day before disable time

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I have a working code for almost everything I need but still need help with one more thing.

```
jQuery("#date_num").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(d) {
            var day = d.getDay();
            var array = ['28/09/2020', '20/09/2020'];
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', d);
            return [(day != 6 && array.indexOf(string) === -1)];
        },
        minDate: +0,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var day = jQuery(this).datepicker("getDate").getDay();
            jQuery("p#time_num_friday_field").toggle(day === 5);
            jQuery("p#time_num_field").toggle(day !== 5);
            var selectedDate = jQuery('#date_num').datepicker('getDate');
            var today = new Date();
            today.setHours(0);
            today.setMinutes(0);
            today.setSeconds(0);
            if (Date.parse(today) === Date.parse(selectedDate)) {
                jQuery( "#time_num option, #time_num_friday option" ).each(function() {
                    var dt = new Date();
                    //dt.setHours(dt.getHours()+4);
                    var time = (dt.getHours()<10?'0':'') + dt.getHours() + ":" + (dt.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + dt.getMinutes();
                    var value = jQuery(this).val();
                        if(time >= value){    
                            jQuery(this).prop("disabled", true);
                        }
                });
            } else {
                jQuery( "#time_num option, #time_num_friday option" ).each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).prop("disabled", false);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I need another thing is to disable dropdown custom hours list. Let me explain exactly what I need.

1: a day is disabled on a date picker with this: `var array = ['28/09/2020', '20/09/2020'];`

2: If those dates are disabled I need to disable the dropdown hours list disabled a day before - if let's say I have hours from 9am to 6pm and I disabled tomorrow date so I need to disable hours fom 12am to 6pm (like a friday day).

Thanks for the helpers in advance.

p.s.
Just to make it more clear.
a person can order today or tomorrow a delivery or a pickup from 9am to 6pm, If I disable tomorrow for deliveries I need the time of today to be 9am to 12am - basically every hour after 12am is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long night I have managed to solve my own request ( Hurray for me lol )

What I did is taking the dates array and dissolving it by jQuery.each so they both can be separate.

Took the date that selected by the datePicker and decreased a day so if the selected day is 09/27/2020 it will show the right dropdown field.

Basically 09/27/2020 = 09/28/2020 and 09/28/2020 = 09/27/2020 for the dropdown

```
var dates = ['09/28/2020'];
jQuery("#date_num").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        var day = d.getDay();
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', d);
        var hide = dates.indexOf(string) === -1;
        return [(day != 6 && hide)];
    },
    minDate: +0,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var selectedDate = jQuery(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var day = jQuery(this).datepicker("getDate").getDay();
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', selectedDate);
        jQuery.each(dates, function(index,value) {
            var dateNow = new Date(string);
            var daysST = -1; 
            dateNow.setDate(dateNow.getDate() - daysST);
            var dateSub = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', dateNow); 
            var innerDay = dateNow.getDay() -1;                     
            checkArray(dateSub, dates);         
            function checkArray(dateSub, dates) {
              if (dates.indexOf(dateSub) !== -1) {
                jQuery("p#time_num_friday_field").toggle(day === innerDay);
                jQuery("p#time_num_field").toggle(day !== innerDay);
              } else {
                jQuery("p#time_num_friday_field").toggle(day === 5);
                jQuery("p#time_num_field").toggle(day !== 5);
              }
            }           
        });
        var today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0);
        today.setMinutes(0);
        today.setSeconds(0);
        if (Date.parse(today) === Date.parse(selectedDate)) {
            jQuery( "#time_num option, #time_num_friday option" ).each(function() {
                var dt = new Date();
                //dt.setHours(dt.getHours()+4);
                var time = (dt.getHours()<10?'0':'') + dt.getHours() + ":" + (dt.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + dt.getMinutes();
                var value = jQuery(this).val();
                    if(time >= value){    
                        jQuery(this).prop("disabled", true);
                    }
            });
        } else {
            jQuery( "#time_num option, #time_num_friday option" ).each(function() {
                jQuery(this).prop("disabled", false);
            });
        }
    }
});
```